# Lock Resizable jQuery UI to vertical resize only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm basically looking to lock this resizable element to a vertical resize only. I know that you can use minWidth/maxWidth and all that, but this sets the min and max to a specific number value, and if I resize the browser window these numbers are no longer accurate. Thoughts on how I could lock the resize?

Here is a code snippet:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
  } );
  </script>
<body>
 
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
 
 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [handles](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles):

```js
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({
    handles: 'n, s'
});
```

```css
#resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
#resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQueryUI Resizable has 2 options that can be used to do this:

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({
   minWidth:150,
   maxWidth:150
});
```